# Remove and Re-Create Element on event:

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to remove an entire element and recreate it on an event:
I cannot seem to get this right despite several variations of the same code:

For example on event, I need to remove the element and then recreate the same element. I do not want to remove the text:

This is what I have tried (experimental): The result is inconsistent and the code is repetitive.

```
function removeCreate(){

    var input = document.getElementById('display');
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    if(!!input){
        input.parentNode.removeChild(input);
        input = document.createElement('input');
        input.id = 'display';
        input.setAttribute('type',"text");
        body.appendChild(input);

    } else {
        input.parentNode.removeChild(input);
        input = document.createElement('input');
        input.id = 'display';
        input.setAttribute('type',"text");
        body.appendChild(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind giving some example of inconsistent results? It would also be helpful to provide a self-contained example such as a snippet (or fiddle) so we can produce the results ourselves.

Comment: By inconsistent I mean, the tag gets created and not removed or removed and not recreated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean about not wanting to remove the text? If you remove an element its text and child elements will be gone.

Comment: Your `if` and `else` blocks look identical. What are you trying to achieve and Why ?

Answer (score 0):

Your reason for removing your input element and re-creating it is quite unclear, but let's say it gets modified somehow and you want to "reset" its state.

When you say "I do not want to remove the text", the most probable thing I understand is that you want to keep the current value that the user has typed into your input.

If this fits your situation, then you could simply hold a "template" of your input element in memory, so that you can clone it when needed and use the clone to replace the one in DOM. When doing so, retrieve first the current input value, and inject it back into the cloned input.

Result:

```js
var inputTemplate = document.createElement('input');
inputTemplate.setAttribute('type', 'text');

function cloneInput() {
    var newInput = inputTemplate.cloneNode(true);
    newInput.id = 'display';

    return newInput;
}

var input = document.getElementById('display');
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

if(!!input){
    // First retrieve the current value (what the user has typed / default value)
    var value = input.value;
    input.parentNode.removeChild(input);
    input = cloneInput();
    input.value = value; // Re-inject the value.
    body.appendChild(input); // Note that this would put your input at the bottom of the page.

} else {
    //input.parentNode.removeChild(input); // useless?
    input = cloneInput();
    body.appendChild(input);
}
```